# Why use (ps -f&) to display process information, and then display the PPID of 1 instead of the PID of the main shell (-bash)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, centos

When I use `(ps -f&)` to display the process information, I found that its PPID is `1`, I am confused, why is it not the PID of the main shell (`-bash`)? I continued to execute the same command twice, and produced a strange process (`[bash] <defunct>`) with the following output:

- The first test:

  ```
  [root@localhost ~]# (ps -f&)
  UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  root       2078   2076  0 01:44 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
  root       2244      1  0 03:07 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
  ```
- The second test:

  ```
  [root@localhost ~]# (ps -f&)
  UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  root       2078   2076  0 01:44 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
  root       2245   2078  0 03:07 pts/0    00:00:00 [bash] <defunct>
  root       2246      1  0 03:07 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
  ```

I tested it many times and found that the `[bash] <defunct>` process rarely appears (occasionally), but the PPID of the `ps -f` process is always 1.

My question is:

1. Why is the PPID of `ps -f` `1` instead of the PID of the main shell (-bash)?
2. What is the strange `[bash] <defunct>` process? Why didn't it appear in the first test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `( ps -f & )` with the ampersand, the subshell doesn't wait on the `ps` process so chances are it'll exit sooner than `ps`. If it does, `ps` no longer has a parent who'd reap its exit status with `wait`/`waitpid`/`waitid` so what happens on UNIXes is such processes (so called [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process)) get reparented, normally to the [init process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) (pid == 1) (Linux also allows for the concept of subreapers other than init).

What you're seeing in the second test is a temporary zombie. When a child process exits, it becomes a zombie ([defunct]) until its parent reaps its exit information. You must have caught the subshell at a moment where it exited but its parent (your main shell) hasn't managed to reap its exit info yet. Unless the parent shell is blocked in some way from continuing and thereby reaping the exit info, this should be only a temporary, transient state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to ask you to recommend me some useful books about these.

Comment: @Treason No problem. "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment" is the classic.